# How to get full Stdout from exec.Command?

Tags: go

I have this code which I would also want to get the full output from `cmd.Stdout` when its done for text extraction, etc.

```
func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("readinggame")
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Run()
}
```

I can't seem to find a way of getting the output either as `[]byte` or `string` when its done. BTW I don't want to be iterating over the output with `ReadLine` (or something similar) which happens to work well, I just want a full output at a go, something like

```
var out bytes.Buffer
cmd.Stdout = &out
if err := cmd.Run(); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
fmt.Println(out.String())
```

Comment: What's wrong with using the bytes.Buffer? Why not use `cmd.Output` or `cmd.CombinedOutput`?

Comment: With the `bytes.Buffer` the error is that I can't get anything out of `cmd.Stdout` since I've already streamed all the data to `os.Stdout`. I can't use `cmd.Output` bcos I want to stream the output to the `os.Stdout`... in the case of a long-running application

Answer (score 4):

This is EXACTLY the expected result... all that was needed was `io.MultiWriter`.

```
func main() {

    cmd := exec.Command("ping", "google.com")

    var out bytes.Buffer
    multi := io.MultiWriter(os.Stdout, &out)
    cmd.Stdout = multi

    if err := cmd.Run(); err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("\n*** FULL OUTPUT *** %s\n", out.String())

}
```